# W3C markup validation: Attribute 'ng-transition' not allowed on element 'style' at this point

Tags: html, angular8, w3c-validation

I am using Angular universal and getting the error Attribute 'ng-transition' not allowed on element 'style' at this point.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: is issue still there? you got any solution regarding this

Comment: yes, still not found any solution for that.

Comment: can u check gulp-js for angular will resolve these issues